# How are rvalues assigned to lvalues in assembly?

Tags: c++, assembly, stack, rvalue

First question here. I will in a few weeks/months need to create procedural code in which there will be functions assigning big (I mean really big) sets of data directly to pointers. Here is some example of code I will be doing :

```
void MyFuntion(string* str)
{
     *str = "some data in a string";
}
```

As it surely is important : I am on windows 10, in visual-studio 2019, compiling with the default c++ compiler on release x86.

Imagine something like this but with strings that can contain several millions of characters, or with int/float arrays also with several millions of elements.
So, this is a single operation assigning a rvalue to a pointer, which is therefore on the heap. Of course, if I create a local variable containing the data, it will be more than 1MB and therefore will cause a stack overflow, right ?

As I understand, since the data only exists as a rvalue here, it doesn't have a memory existence, but I would like to know : how is the rvalue assigned to the pointer ? Like, how is it done in assembly ? I must say I have never done any assembly, I have a few (very few) notions but I'd like to get into it when I have time.

Is it temporary created in the stack or heap before being put in the final memory address ? My guess is that the memory address (the pointer in which I am assigning the data) is directly filled with the data, like, bit by bit, so no existence of the rvalue in memory.

If I'm correct, the only things that exist in the stack here are : the function call, the pointer copy, then the instruction, which should be something like "assign rvalue X to lvalue Y" and the size of the instruction doesn't depend on the size of the rvalue and lvalue, so there should not be any problem regarding the stack here.

So, if I'm correct, this code should not cause any problem, no matter how big the rvalue is, but I would still like to know how it is done exactly, assembly-wise. Note that I am not only looking for an answer, but more like some references, books or docs, that could explain in detail. I guess what I am looking for won't be in a c++ book, but more like a assembly book, this might be a good starting point to get myself into it !

Comment: Why not look at the assembly output?

Comment: FYI: [Asm in Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/a5jde7x3n) The output of MSVC is a bit hard to read as there is added something of the built-in stuff. I added the output of `g++` which looks cleaner but does basically something similar.

Comment: If `string` here is `std::string`, then this is not just a simple variable assignment but will call the string's assignment operator. This looks different in assembly than assignment of a primitive type.

Comment: The character array `"some data in a string"` actually does exist in the memory, or more precisely it can be found directly in the executable which is loaded into memory. The rvalue is not the character array but a pointer to the character array, so all the function does is assign a pointer to a (std?) string.

Comment: @olm: `std::string`' assignment operator is overloaded; it's actually a function call that takes the `const char*` as an arg.  (And that function can get inlined.  For short string literals, the compiler might decide to optimize away the pointer and static storage, and just embed the string data into instructions like `mov rax, "foo bar"` / `mov [rdx], rax` for an 8-byte string (including terminating 0).  (NASM syntax for multi-char constant as an immediate; GAS doesn't let you write it that way.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, but I am not sure these details (especially the possible optimization) are what is actually being asked about.
As I read the question, they assume that in `foo = huge_immediate_data;` the data never exists anywhere before the instruction, and are guessing that it will be translated to a large number of `mov` instructions with immediate values. 
I was trying to point out that there is such a thing as the static storage.

Comment: @olm: yeah, after reading more of the question, agreed.  IDK exactly what misconceptions the querent has, but they include the idea that an instruction itself could be on the stack.  (It can't.)  So yeah, a loop that copies from static storage is the key point for what the constructor will do when passed a `char*` rvalue, in the C++ abstract machine.  Optimization from that point is up to the compiler, but yeah there's no reason for any use of the stack at all, except for a return address.  A couple scalar things like a pointer can fit in registers.

Comment: @PeterCordes By static storage, do you mean the BBS, Data and Text segments as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) ? If I understand correctly, the rvalue will be stored in the Data section, right ? Then I guess the data will be kept as long as the program is running ? I read that the Data segment's size is 256MB (at least on linux, didn't find for windows), is there a way to make that this rvalue is only stored when the function is called, then freed ? I only need to call each function once, but I need a lot of them with different rvalues each.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think I misunderstood the wikipedia link. The BSS and Data segments only deal with static or global variables, right ? So, the line `*str = "some data in a string";` only writes the rvalue directly at the adress pointed by str, it never exists in any segment by itself, only ends in the heap after it is assigned ? In the end, what I want to do won't cause any problem (as long as I  don't exceed the RAM size of course), I can have as many rvalues as I want.

Comment: Yes, C's "static storage class" is where the characters of string literals live, along with global and `static` variables.  Those are normally implemented with assembly-language static storage, which yes includes `.data`, `.bss`, `.rodata` (where you'll find string literals and other constants), and the `.text` section where you'll find machine code.  (Remember, C and C++ are designed for ahead-of-time compilation, no need for run-time code-gen onto the heap or stack.  Only function *pointers* and stuff like return addresses get stored on the asm stack in a normal implementation).

Comment: *only writes the rvalue directly at the adress pointed by str* - no, in C++ it runs the `std::string::operator=(const char*)` function on the pointed-to `std::string` object to `delete` the old string and build a new one from the pointed-to C string.  The pointer-to-string-literal rvalue becomes a function arg.  If you'd picked an example with a primitive type like `const char **str`, then yes, you'd just be storing a pointer (to static storage) into the 4 or 8 byte pointer object pointed-to by `str`, wherever that is (stack, "heap", .data or .bss).

Comment: e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/GK4a676sd (use the dropdown to unfilter "directives" to see the `.section .rodata` and `.text` directives compilers use to put stuff in different parts of the executable, i.e. different parts of static storage for code and constant data.  But note that until the last couple years, `.rodata` and `.text` sections normally got linked into the same *segment* of an ELF executable, part of the same read-only+exec mapping.  But recently GNU binutils `ld` started using a different segment so .rodata could be mapped without exec permission, because of Spectre / ROP attacks)

Answer (score 2):

Although a specific OS and compiler were mentioned, the example assembly in this answer will probably differ from what the querent's compiler would output, because I don't have a Windows 10 machine available at the time of writing and used a different environment <s>having forgotten about Godbolt</s>. However, this topic is general enough in my opinion that it shouldn't really matter in this specific case.

---

What even is a value on the right side of an assignment operator? What does assignment look like at the assembly level? Here's a simple example.

```cpp
void assign_thing(int *p) {
    *p = 42;
}
```

```
movl $42, (%rdi)
retq
```

"Move the 32-bit integer `42` into the memory location to which `rdi` is pointing." `%rdi` here represents `p`, and `(%rdi)` means `*p`. For something dead simple like an integer, it's pretty much that simple. How about a simple structure?

```cpp
struct stuff {
    int id;
    float value;
    char text[8];
};

void assign_thing(stuff *p) {
    *p = {42, 1.5, "Hello!"};
}
```

```
movabsq $4593671619917905962, %rax
movq    %rax, (%rdi)
movabsq $36762444129608, %rax
movq    %rax, 8(%rdi)
retq
```

A little harder to read at first glance, but pretty much the same idea. The compiler was smart and packed the integer and float values `42` and `1.5` into a single 64-bit value and stuffs that directly into `(%rdi)`. Likewise with the string `"Hello!"`, which is short enough to fit into a single 64-bit value and gets stuffed into `8(%rdi)` (8 bytes past `p` is the offset of `text`).

---

So far, none of the rvalues actually exist in memory when they get assigned. They're just part of the instructions. What if it's something a lot bigger, like a string?

```
// Overflow checking omitted for brevity.
void assign_thing(char *p) {
    // Assignment with = doesn't actually do what you'd want here,
    // so this'll have to do.
    strcpy(p, "What if it's something a lot bigger, like a string?");
}
```

```
vmovups -5484(%rip), %ymm0
vmovups %ymm0, 20(%rdi) ; I'm guessing the disassembler meant to say 0x20
vmovups -5517(%rip), %ymm0
vmovups %ymm0, (%rdi)
vzeroupper
retq
```

Now, the rvalue *does* reside in memory when it gets assigned. Do note that this is not because `strcpy` was used instead of `=`, but because the compiler decided that it would be better to store that "rvalue" string somewhere in a read-only area like `.rodata` and just copy it over. If I had used a much shorter string, any reasonably modern compiler would probably optimize it into a few `mov` or `movabsq` instructions like in the second example. Unless `p` points to a buffer on the stack and your `strcpy` ends up overflowing it, you won't get a stack overflow here.

---

Now what about your example? I'm guessing that your `string` type is really `std::string`, and that's not a trivial type. So what happens there? In C++, the assignment operator `=` is overloadable, and `std::string` indeed has its own overloads, so instead of directly stuffing or copying values into the object, a special member function `operator=` is called. That is to say, your `*str = "some data in a string"` is really a `str->operator=("some data in a string")`. How your rvalue string gets copied is up to the implementation of `std::string::operator=`, but it'll most likely be optimized into something like my last example. The actual string data of an `std::string` resides on the heap, so stack overflow still isn't a problem here.

---

**tl;dr** (this answer + the comments, compressed into a few sentences)

If your string is small enough, it probably won't exist in memory during assignment. If it's big enough, it'll sit in a read-only area somewhere and get copied over when needed. The stack is often not even involved, so don't worry about overflow.